# How to use headless chrome in python on vercel?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, vercel

You may know that heroku will stop their free dyno, free postgres etc from November. So I was finding some alternative to run my python web apps. I have almost 10 regular web apps which I visit regularly, like: url shortener, keyword research, google drive direct link generator site and many more. All of these are hosted on heroku. But I'm moving to vercel now. I setup all projects on vercel but the last one is complicated. My last project is python selenium bot. This one is my keyword research web app. I used some buildpack eg: Headless Chrome (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) and Chromedriver (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver) to make this project run properly. But the problem is I could not find anything like buildpack in vercel to add Chrome and Chromedriver.
Anyone know about this?

### Edit:

That was a kind of story and many people didn’t understand what I was asking.

So, My project is about selenium (python). Selenium needs google chrome browser installed and a chromedriver to run itself. There is another option without installing chrome is to set chrome binary location in `webdriver.ChromeOptions()`. I want to host this selenium project on vercel.com which is linux based.

So my question is how can I install Chrome Browser and ChromeDriver in vercel?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.